# How to fix "Could not load JavaScript 'content.js' for content script" error

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension

I'm following this [video](https://youtu.be/9Tl3OmwrSaM?list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6bL9VOMT65ahNEri9uqLWfS) and have also enabled json formatter extension. But can anyone help me understand why the below error is produced:

*this is the manifest.json file*

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Cool Extension",
  "version": "0.001",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

*this is the content.js file*

```
console.log("My First Attempt");
```

Comment: It means there's no content.js in the same folder as manifest.json or you didn't reload the extension on chrome://extensions page or you're looking at an old error that's no longer applicable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @wOxxOm How do you cause webpack to put it in the same folder, i.e. into `dist/` and not into `dist/js/`?

Comment: If it's in `js` then specify the path as "js/content.js". All paths in manifest.json are relative to manifest.json.

Answer (score 0):

i was having same issue using vite build, the problem was script file not getting copied while building, this the change i did in custom script.

```js
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "build-extension": "npm run build && copy src\\manifest.json dist\\ && copy src\\Content.js dist\\",
  },
```

need to add content script inside build folder.

Comment: note: you need to run following command ->>  npm run build-extension